# Why isn't my json object being stored to my sqlite db

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a PHone Gap app with steroids js. I'm trying to get remote JSON and store it in a sqlite db using the Cordova Storage API. For some reason, I'm unable to do this. The database is not populated with the JSON. Here's my script

```
function getStuff(num) {
    $http.jsonp('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://catholic.com/api-radio/' + num) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function (response) {

         var result = angular.fromJson(response.contents);

var JSONvar = result;
function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "'+ JSONvar +'")');
}
function errorCB(err) {
alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
alert("success!");
}


var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```